# Bad notification: The given region must intersect with the Bitmap's dimensions

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-bitmap, android-image

I'm getting an exception on Crashlytics for a small amount of users. For most users it seems to work fine but for some it fails (tiny amount but I'm only on a staged release right now). I think the issue might be that I scale down the bitmap I use on the notification, I use this code to scale it down:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, true);
```

The exception is this:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package mypacakge: Couldn't inflate contentViewsjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given region must intersect with the Bitmap's dimensions.
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1881)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: I did a search of Android code to see who throws that exception and it appears to be the `Palette` builder, I then searched for code related to notifications that uses `Palette` and the `setRegion()` method and found this on `MediaNotificationProcessor.java`:

```
Palette.Builder paletteBuilder = Palette.from(bitmap)
                        .setRegion(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight())
                        .clearFilters() // we want all colors, red / white / black ones too!
                        .resizeBitmapArea(RESIZE_BITMAP_AREA);
                Palette palette = paletteBuilder.generate();
                backgroundColor = findBackgroundColorAndFilter(palette);
                // we want most of the full region again, slightly shifted to the right
                float textColorStartWidthFraction = 0.4f;
                paletteBuilder.setRegion((int) (bitmap.getWidth() * textColorStartWidthFraction), 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(),
                        bitmap.getHeight());
                if (mFilteredBackgroundHsl != null) {
                    paletteBuilder.addFilter((rgb, hsl) -> {
                        // at least 10 degrees hue difference
                        float diff = Math.abs(hsl[0] - mFilteredBackgroundHsl[0]);
                        return diff > 10 && diff < 350;
                    });
                }
```

So my guess is that in here it is passing some bad value but I have no idea what. I have added a few more logs for Fabric for this error, hopefully I'll get more data soon.

Comment: why are you scaling down? Create a new icon for bitmap icon for the notification purpose only as per requirement.

Comment: I had some phones that had a crash when calling `notify()`, something about parcel being too large or something like that, so I assumed the issue was the bitmap so I decided to scale it as a test. I haven't had anymore of the other crash (parcel one) though this is an early beta so it could be too early to know for sure.

Comment: If developer explicitly wants a large icon to be there with a small icon too, then we have to provide bitmap image as parameter for the large icon only. and Large icon is not compulsory at all, you can neglect it too, still if you wants large icon too, then do not scale down

Comment: Large icon on a notification is pretty small, the images I'm putting there are really large to start with, meant to be shown on the full screen of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

It is a working code, hope it helps you, or someone else...

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_xy";
CharSequence name = "my_channel";
String Description = "This is my channel";
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 19920901; 

Log.d("FileCreator : ","Notification Creating...:"+NOTIFICATION_ID);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
      int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
      NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
      mChannel.setDescription(Description);
      mChannel.enableLights(true);
      mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
      mChannel.enableVibration(true);
      mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100});
      mChannel.setShowBadge(true);

      if (notificationManager != null)
      {
           notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
      }

}

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("MYVAR", "MYVAL");
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

//resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("NextTitle")
                    .setContentText("NextText")
                    .setTicker("NextText")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("NextMessage it is a long text which is replaced when user swipes it down from the notification tray..."))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mynotification)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));

if (notificationManager != null)
{
      notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
      Log.d("FileCreator : ", "NOTIFIED TO THE USER... \n");
}
else
{
      Log.d("FileCreator : ", "COULD NOT BE NOTIFIED TO THE USER...????!!!! \n");
}
```

This should work across the devices, with both of the icons in the notifications.